# cannot get parameters from queryParam when using event input in Dialogflow v2

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I would like to print out in the response the parameters given when the request is made to Dialogflow but for some reason this is not working for me.

This is the request:

```
request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
          event: {
            name: 'questionevt',
            parameters: {
              question: 'this is a question'
            },
            languageCode: 'en-US',
          },
        },
      };
```

and my Dialogflow response looks like this:
[image]

Any idea why this is not working, it is showing empty like nothing beeing binded there.

EDIT:
Strangely when I try to print out `console.log(result.parameters.fields.question);` I see `{ stringValue: '', kind: 'stringValue' }` as a msg!

Comment: I think your request might be wrong, event data is passed under the `data` key, not `parameters`. See this example from the docs: https://dialogflow.com/docs/events#post_query_request

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a default text response, in fact, you need to enable webhook call for that intent in the fulfillment section. I'll show you how my intent looks like.

[image: Intent]

My entity:

[image: Entity]

The code in the fulfillment section (you need to enable the inline editor):

```js
'use strict';
const http = require('http');

const kind = 'ticket';
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = (req, res) => {
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  
  let question = req.body.queryResult.parameters['question'];
  
  switch(question){
      case "computer":
          res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'fulfillmentText': "Restart the computer."}));
          break;
      case "love":
          res.send(JSON.stringify({ 'fulfillmentText': "Forget him/her."}));
          break;
  }
}
```

then, if you try it out it should work like that:

[image: Result]